# value of the variable - nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

It looks like the error I'm receiving in my application is caused by the fact that @ad object is somehow becomes nil. The only thing I have in mind at the moment is to see step-by-step what's going on in rails console. 
This is the code from the controller:

```
def edit
  @ad=Ad.find(params[:id])
end
```

So first step I want to check in rails console if the @ad=Ad.find(params[:id]) actually works.
So I type in console

```
@ad=Ad.find(id=5)
```

and receive the output

```
"  ←[1m←[36mAd Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "ads".* FROM "ads" WHERE "ads"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 5]]
=> #<Ad id: 5, name: "Door curtain", description: "Beaded door cu...", price: #<BigDecimal:40be0e8,'0.11E2',4(8)>, selle
r_id: 773, email: "dawn@hotmail....", img_url: "http://www.freewebsit...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>"
```

OK, this step works.
The next step I want to do is to see what happens if @ad is printed on the screen - this way I will be able to see what is exactly is passed to the view.
I type 'print @ad in this is the output that is given:

```
irb(main):025:0> print @ad
#<Ad:0x40be700>=> nil
irb(main):026:0> puts @ad
#<Ad:0x40be700>
=> nil
```

1. Does that really mean that for some reason @ad is passed as nill to the view?
2. Is there any problem with my logic here? (newbe)

Comment: Also, the reason your last line in the console reads `nil` is not because the object is nil, but because the return value of `puts` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `print @ad` Rails actually calls `print @ad.to_s` (to convert the Ad to a string). You need to define your `.to_s` method in the Ad model

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Or if you're just debugging:

```
print @ad.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

`#<Ad:0x40be700>` means that this an active_record hash.
If you `puts @ad.name` or `puts @ad.inspect in console`, you'll see your values